# Does it matter if GTM is capturing a click event as gtm.click rather than gtm.linkClick?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I am looking for some advice on Google Tag Manager click events.

Our client has requested that a certain click should be captured as `gtm.linkClick` event. However, the element in question is a button that will trigger routing within an Angular Application. This button click is being captured as `gtm.click`.

My question is, does that matter? Will this provide less information or can I configure GTM tags to grab the same information?

Comment: You mean apart from the fact that they target different elements ("click" targets all elements, "linkClick" just anchor tags) ?

Answer (score 6):

In GTM a click-based trigger has two options: if you want it to only listen for clicks on regular links ("Just Links" option) or for clicks on any HTML element on the page ("All Elements" option).

`gtm.linkClick` event is `Click - Just Links` trigger type in GTM
`gtm.click` event is `Click - All Elements` trigger type in GTM

If user is clicking to `<a>` HTML tag, it's firing `gtm.linkClick` event, in other case, if user click in other any html tag(buttons,images,span, divs and etc), it will fire `gtm.click`

**One tricky moment.**

You might want to track click on complex `<div>` which contains child elements. `gtm.click` might fire on children html tags.

For example if you have markup

```
<div id="parent">text <span>child1</span> and <div>child2</div></div>
```

And you want to crack clicks on `#parent` div. In this case, better way to do that is to have trigger condition

```
Click Element - matches CSS selector - `#parent, #parent *`
```

It will trigger if click will happen on `#parent` div or in one of his child